# Java - Check Boxes in a JComboBox

Tags: java, user-interface

I would like to make a JComboBox that has check boxes for items instead of text. In addition, it should be possible to check multiple items and retrieve the selected items from the component. Should I be make a custom ComboBoxUI, ComboBoxEditor, ListCellRenderer, ComboPopUp, or something different entirely? Is there an existing Java control that does this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was fairly easy to implement. Found it here [link text](http://www.aui.computing.edu.au/projects/Outcomes_Focused_Education/resources/graph/JComboCheckBox.java)

```
/* * The following code is adapted from Java Forums - JCheckBox in JComboBox URL: http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=257&threadID=364705 Date of Access: July 28 2005 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JComboCheckBox extends JComboBox {
  public JComboCheckBox() { addStuff(); }
  public JComboCheckBox(JCheckBox[] items) { super(items); addStuff(); }
  public JComboCheckBox(Vector items) { super(items); addStuff(); }
  public JComboCheckBox(ComboBoxModel aModel) { super(aModel); addStuff(); }
  private void addStuff() {
    setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());
    addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { itemSelected(); }
    });
  }
  private void itemSelected() {
    if (getSelectedItem() instanceof JCheckBox) {
      JCheckBox jcb = (JCheckBox)getSelectedItem();
      jcb.setSelected(!jcb.isSelected());
    }
  }
  class ComboBoxRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {
    private JLabel defaultLabel;
    public ComboBoxRenderer() { setOpaque(true); }
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      if (value instanceof Component) {
        Component c = (Component)value;
        if (isSelected) {
          c.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
          c.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
          c.setBackground(list.getBackground());
          c.setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }
        return c;
      } else {
        if (defaultLabel==null) defaultLabel = new JLabel(value.toString());
        else defaultLabel.setText(value.toString());
        return defaultLabel;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can't imagine that anybody wants the change the check-box selected along with comboModel selected

Comment: I used your example to create a sample and got that we can not select data from drop down on key press.
e.g. if combo text is First, second etc.. 
 User press "S" key, 
 Second should be highlighted/selected. Just like in normal JComboBox.
 Is there any way to do it as in one of my application we need it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what combo boxes are "for". Are you sure you don't want, say, a JMenu with `JRadioButtonMenuItem`s?

If you *do* really want to proceed, then you'd use a custom renderer, as you [suggested](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).

Answer (score 1):

We were once given this same inane requirement as well.  We complied with a brand new component.
It was essentially a `JPanel` which had a text field and a down arrow button.   It contained a `JList` which used a `JCheckbox`-derrived `ListCellRenderer`. The `JList` was packaged in a `JPopupMenu`
which was displayed on mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [japura](https://github.com/caduandrade/japura-gui/wiki). It's a open source custom component based on swing.