# Can JCheckBox components be added to JComboBoxes?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jcheckbox

Can JCheckBox components be added to JComboBoxes?  If so, how?

Comment: use `CellRenderer` to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a JCheckBox to a JComboBox? What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a JComboBox i.e, list of items from that i need to select some items from that JComboBox list..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to jimmy JCheckBoxes into a JComboBoxes, but it's not nearly as straightforward as using them in a JTable since JComboBoxes don't use cell editors, only renderers.  Let's see if I can re-find this on Google....

Please check here: [JComboCheckBox](http://www.aui.computing.edu.au/projects/Outcomes_Focused_Education/resources/graph/JComboCheckBox.java)
and here: [Check Boxes in a Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573159/java-check-boxes-in-a-jcombobox)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CheckCombo implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        CheckComboStore store = (CheckComboStore)cb.getSelectedItem();
        CheckComboRenderer ccr = (CheckComboRenderer)cb.getRenderer();
        ccr.checkBox.setSelected((store.state = !store.state));
    }

    private JPanel getContent()
    {
        String[] ids = { "north", "west", "south", "east" };
        Boolean[] values =
        {
            Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE
        };
        CheckComboStore[] stores = new CheckComboStore[ids.length];
        for(int j = 0; j < ids.length; j++)
            stores[j] = new CheckComboStore(ids[j], values[j]);
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(stores);
        combo.setRenderer(new CheckComboRenderer());
        combo.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(combo);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new CheckCombo().getContent());
        f.setSize(300,160);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

/** adapted from comment section of ListCellRenderer api */
class CheckComboRenderer implements ListCellRenderer
{
    JCheckBox checkBox;

    public CheckComboRenderer()
    {
        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
    }
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                                  Object value,
                                                  int index,
                                                  boolean isSelected,
                                                  boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        CheckComboStore store = (CheckComboStore)value;
        checkBox.setText(store.id);
        checkBox.setSelected(((Boolean)store.state).booleanValue());
        checkBox.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.red : Color.white);
        checkBox.setForeground(isSelected ? Color.white : Color.black);
        return checkBox;
    }
}

class CheckComboStore
{
    String id;
    Boolean state;

    public CheckComboStore(String id, Boolean state)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what anyone wants: open the dropdown and navigate by keyboard in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [Japura-GUI](https://github.com/caduandrade/japura-gui/wiki) library, which provides a CheckComboBox component for creating JComboBoxes with checkboxes.
You can find detailed documentation and usage examples for the Japura-GUI CheckComboBox [here](https://github.com/caduandrade/japura-gui/wiki/CheckComboBox)

Simply follow the documentation to integrate the CheckComboBox into your Java Swing application.