# java Swing JCombobox multiple selection using ctrl key

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, multipleselection

I am trying to create JCombobox with multiple selection by holding ctrl key.
i have created Jcombobox for multiple selection by overinding ListCellRenderer.
it is working fine on selecting one by one .
but i required to select multiple using ctrl or shift key any way to achieve this.

Comment: I would consider making it a [JCombobox with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573159/java-check-boxes-in-a-jcombobox). A dropdown that uses CTRL-click for multiple items is counter intuitive.

Comment: Even when i use checkboxes on checking one combo box it got hide to check other i need to click on jocmbobox again so what i need until and unless i made my selection jcombobox should not hide

Comment: Do the end user a favor and instead offer a `JList` (that allows multiple selection).

Comment: Client wants jcombobox with multiple selection using ctrl key . that is our requirement we could not change it

Comment: User wants a GUI that is not counterintuitive. Your client does not garner enough cause for me to help in this travesty.

Comment: @AndrewThompson "User wants a GUI that is not counterintuitive". I think you mean "not intuitive" or "counterintuitive". Or maybe I am just missing your point here :)